# how can I retrieve the dashboard ID from inside an apex controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Visual Force page used as a component in more than one dashboard.

How can I retrieve the current Dashboard ID from inside the apex controller?

Answer (score 0):

Since your VF page is just an iFrame on the dashboard page, just get the referer url, which will have the 15 digit dashboard ID immediately after ".com/".

```
String parentURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer');
String comStr = '.com/';
Integer comIndex = parentURL.indexOf(comStr) + comStr.length();
String dashboardID = parentURL.substring(comIndex,comIndex+15);
```

Comment: Thank you @caleb.breckon, I tried but I don't get the dashboard Id after ".com/"

Comment: What value does `parentURL` return in your controller?

Comment: parentURL='https://cs12.salesforce.com/' I din't get the Id